# Pandas calculation within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Have a simple pandas dataframe like that:

```
      period        count
       0            4000
       1            20000
```

How can I perform calcualtion 4000/(4000+20000) using pandas syntax and this dataframe?

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate? Why would you have a DataFrame like this? It's complete overkill and only makes what you are trying to do difficult. Something like `df.loc[0,'count'] / (df.loc[0, 'count'] + df.loc[1, 'count'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `rolling` method to sum and then divide.

```
df['count'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x[0] / x.sum()).dropna()

1    0.166667
```